# error installing (or compiling) eventmachine-1.0.0.beta.3 rubygem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

due to rubygem dependencies, `eventmachine` version 1.0.0.beta.3 needs to be installed. installing the rubygem as follows, results in error. enclosed a snippet for convenience.

```
$ sudo gem install eventmachine -v '1.0.0.beta.3'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing eventmachine:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby2.0 extconf.rb
checking for rb_trap_immediate in ruby.h,rubysig.h... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for inotify_init() in sys/inotify.h... yes
checking for writev() in sys/uio.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_check_ints()... yes
checking for rb_time_new()... yes
checking for sys/event.h... no
checking for epoll_create() in sys/epoll.h... yes
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
compiling cmain.cpp
compiling kb.cpp
kb.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void KeyboardDescriptor::Read()’:
kb.cpp:77:27: warning: ignoring return value of ‘ssize_t read(int, void*, size_t)’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
  read (GetSocket(), &c, 1);
                           ^
compiling pipe.cpp
compiling binder.cpp
compiling ed.cpp
compiling page.cpp
compiling rubymain.cpp
rubymain.cpp: In function ‘VALUE t_connect_server(VALUE, VALUE, VALUE)’:
rubymain.cpp:504:42: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
   rb_raise (EM_eConnectionError, e.what());
                                          ^
rubymain.cpp: In function ‘VALUE t_bind_connect_server(VALUE, VALUE, VALUE, VALUE, VALUE)’:
rubymain.cpp:525:42: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
   rb_raise (EM_eConnectionError, e.what());
                                          ^
rubymain.cpp: In function ‘VALUE t_watch_filename(VALUE, VALUE)’:
rubymain.cpp:798:38: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
   rb_raise (EM_eUnsupported, e.what());
                                      ^
rubymain.cpp: In function ‘VALUE t_watch_pid(VALUE, VALUE)’:
rubymain.cpp:824:38: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
   rb_raise (EM_eUnsupported, e.what());
                                      ^
rubymain.cpp: In function ‘VALUE t_start_proxy(VALUE, VALUE, VALUE, VALUE, VALUE)’:
rubymain.cpp:1024:42: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
   rb_raise (EM_eConnectionError, e.what());
                                          ^
rubymain.cpp: In function ‘VALUE t_stop_proxy(VALUE, VALUE)’:
rubymain.cpp:1039:42: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
   rb_raise (EM_eConnectionError, e.what());
                                          ^
cc1plus: some warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [rubymain.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0.beta.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0.beta.3/ext/gem_make.out
```

i tried to modify `/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0.beta.3/ext/Makefile` by replacing `-Werror=format-security` with `-Wformat-security`, then running `make`. it installed the the rubygem, though when trying to check whether the rubygem installation has a consistent behaviour. hence, i tried to invoke the command above (`gem install...`) again, but it fails again.

here are few more details on the system:

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.0.0p299 (2013-08-29) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

$ cat /etc/*release* | grep -i distrib
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=13.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=saucy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 13.10"

$ uname -a
Linux user 3.11.0-15-generic #23-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 9 18:17:04 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ gcc --version | grep gcc
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9) 4.8.1
```

i am also familiar with [this fix solution](https://github.com/opscode/em-winrm/issues/6%29%3a), and [this one](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/issues/346), but it does not work for me.
any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

i also tried the following:

```
$ sudo gem install eventmachine -v '1.0.0.beta.3' -- --with-cflags=\"-Wno-error=format-security\"
Building native extensions with: '--with-cflags="-Wno-error=format-security"'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing eventmachine:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby2.0 extconf.rb --with-cflags="-Wno-error=format-security"
checking for rb_trap_immediate in ruby.h,rubysig.h... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for inotify_init() in sys/inotify.h... yes
checking for writev() in sys/uio.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_check_ints()... yes
checking for rb_time_new()... yes
checking for sys/event.h... no
checking for epoll_create() in sys/epoll.h... yes
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
compiling cmain.cpp
compiling kb.cpp
kb.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void KeyboardDescriptor::Read()’:
kb.cpp:77:27: warning: ignoring return value of ‘ssize_t read(int, void*, size_t)’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
  read (GetSocket(), &c, 1);
                           ^
compiling pipe.cpp
compiling binder.cpp
compiling ed.cpp
compiling page.cpp
compiling rubymain.cpp
rubymain.cpp: In function ‘VALUE t_connect_server(VALUE, VALUE, VALUE)’:
rubymain.cpp:504:42: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
   rb_raise (EM_eConnectionError, e.what());
                                          ^
rubymain.cpp: In function ‘VALUE t_bind_connect_server(VALUE, VALUE, VALUE, VALUE, VALUE)’:
rubymain.cpp:525:42: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
   rb_raise (EM_eConnectionError, e.what());
                                          ^
rubymain.cpp: In function ‘VALUE t_watch_filename(VALUE, VALUE)’:
rubymain.cpp:798:38: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
   rb_raise (EM_eUnsupported, e.what());
                                      ^
rubymain.cpp: In function ‘VALUE t_watch_pid(VALUE, VALUE)’:
rubymain.cpp:824:38: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
   rb_raise (EM_eUnsupported, e.what());
                                      ^
rubymain.cpp: In function ‘VALUE t_start_proxy(VALUE, VALUE, VALUE, VALUE, VALUE)’:
rubymain.cpp:1024:42: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
   rb_raise (EM_eConnectionError, e.what());
                                          ^
rubymain.cpp: In function ‘VALUE t_stop_proxy(VALUE, VALUE)’:
rubymain.cpp:1039:42: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
   rb_raise (EM_eConnectionError, e.what());
                                          ^
cc1plus: some warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [rubymain.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0.beta.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0.beta.3/ext/gem_make.out
```

you can see that the flag is not propagated to the compilation of the rubygem.

**UPDATE 2:**

also tried the following:

```
$ sudo gem install eventmachine -v '1.0.0.beta.3' -- --with-cppflags=\"-Wno-error=format-security\"
Building native extensions with: '--with-cppflags="-Wno-error=format-security"'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing eventmachine:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby2.0 extconf.rb --with-cppflags="-Wno-error=format-security"
checking for rb_trap_immediate in ruby.h,rubysig.h... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for inotify_init() in sys/inotify.h... yes
checking for writev() in sys/uio.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_check_ints()... yes
checking for rb_time_new()... yes
checking for sys/event.h... no
checking for epoll_create() in sys/epoll.h... yes
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
compiling cmain.cpp
compiling kb.cpp
kb.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void KeyboardDescriptor::Read()’:
kb.cpp:77:27: warning: ignoring return value of ‘ssize_t read(int, void*, size_t)’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
  read (GetSocket(), &c, 1);
                           ^
compiling pipe.cpp
compiling binder.cpp
compiling ed.cpp
compiling page.cpp
compiling rubymain.cpp
rubymain.cpp: In function ‘VALUE t_connect_server(VALUE, VALUE, VALUE)’:
rubymain.cpp:504:42: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
   rb_raise (EM_eConnectionError, e.what());
                                          ^
rubymain.cpp: In function ‘VALUE t_bind_connect_server(VALUE, VALUE, VALUE, VALUE, VALUE)’:
rubymain.cpp:525:42: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
   rb_raise (EM_eConnectionError, e.what());
                                          ^
rubymain.cpp: In function ‘VALUE t_watch_filename(VALUE, VALUE)’:
rubymain.cpp:798:38: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
   rb_raise (EM_eUnsupported, e.what());
                                      ^
rubymain.cpp: In function ‘VALUE t_watch_pid(VALUE, VALUE)’:
rubymain.cpp:824:38: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
   rb_raise (EM_eUnsupported, e.what());
                                      ^
rubymain.cpp: In function ‘VALUE t_start_proxy(VALUE, VALUE, VALUE, VALUE, VALUE)’:
rubymain.cpp:1024:42: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
   rb_raise (EM_eConnectionError, e.what());
                                          ^
rubymain.cpp: In function ‘VALUE t_stop_proxy(VALUE, VALUE)’:
rubymain.cpp:1039:42: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
   rb_raise (EM_eConnectionError, e.what());
                                          ^
cc1plus: some warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [rubymain.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0.beta.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0.beta.3/ext/gem_make.out
```

**UPDATE 3:**

```
$ sudo gem install eventmachine -v '1.0.0.beta.3' 2>&1 | grep -i inspection
Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0.beta.3 for inspection.

$ grep -i error /var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0.beta.3/ext/Makefile 
CFLAGS   = $(CCDLFLAGS) -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC  $(ARCH_FLAG)
CXXFLAGS = $(CCDLFLAGS) -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security $(ARCH_FLAG)

$ sudo gem install eventmachine -v '1.0.0.beta.3' -- --with-cflags=\"-Wno-error=format-security\" --with-cppflags=\"-Wno-error=format-security\" --with-cxxflags=\"-Wno-error=format-security\" 2>&1 | grep -i inspection
Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0.beta.3 for inspection.

$ grep -i error /var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0.beta.3/ext/Makefile 
CFLAGS   = $(CCDLFLAGS) -Wno-error=format-security  $(ARCH_FLAG)
CPPFLAGS = -DWITH_SSL -DBUILD_FOR_RUBY -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_BLOCKING_REGION -DHAVE_TBR -DHAVE_INOTIFY_INIT -DHAVE_INOTIFY -DHAVE_WRITEV -DHAVE_WRITEV -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_CHECK_INTS -DHAVE_RB_TIME_NEW -DOS_UNIX -DHAVE_EPOLL_CREATE -DHAVE_EPOLL -DHAVE_MAKE_PAIR -Wno-error=format-security
CXXFLAGS = $(CCDLFLAGS) -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security $(ARCH_FLAG)
```

please refer to the `CXXFLAGS`, why the flags which are passed to the comiplation are not being propogated?

Comment: Do you _really_ need `1.0.0.beta.3`? Why not use `1.0.3`? BTW, `gem install eventmachine -v '1.0.0.beta.3' -- --with-cflags=\"-Wno-error=format-security\"` should help (quotes are escaped on purpose.)

Comment: @mudasobwa, i've updated my post above. your offer does not help in compiling the rubygem. i am using that version since it was specified as a dependency for other rubygem.

Comment: I have it compiled like a charm here, so please treat my comments as blind suggestions. Would you try `--with-cppflags=\"-Wno-error=format-security\"` (cpp in place of c).

Comment: @mudasobwa, same. i've updated my post for convenience. and i deeply appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Hmmm. The `export CONFIGURE_ARGS="--with-cflags='-Wno-error=format-security'" && gem install eventmachine -v '1.0.0.beta.3'` shouild finally do the trick. It looks like eventmachine’s `extconf.rb` spits on arguments to `rake build`.

Comment: @mudasobwa, same result. the `CONFIGURE_ARGS` do not propagate to the compilation. even with `export` before it, and executing command in serial.

Comment: Well, I wash my hands of suggestions. It looks weird, since on both Ubuntu cases I have checked everything is compiling without any problem. BTW, `$ gcc --version` is `4.8.1` here.

Comment: @mudasobwa, i really wish to thank you for helping. i am using the latest `gcc` version (i've update my post for convenience). how come that the compilation flags do not propogate?

Comment: @mudasobwa, please refer to my update post (update 3). does it shed more light on the issue?

Comment: Have you already tried `gem install eventmachine -v '1.0.0.beta.3' -- --with-cxxflags=\"-Wno-error=format-security\"` ( **cxx** ), haven’t you?

Comment: @mudasobwa, sure i did. see my 3rd update. and thanks again! :)

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this is an issue with `em-winrm` depending on `eventmachine v1.0.0.beta.3`.

A combination of [mudasobwa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2035262/mudasobwa)'s comment and workaround suggested [here](https://github.com/opscode/em-winrm/issues/6#issuecomment-12237586) worked for me:

```
gem install eventmachine -v '1.0.0.beta.3' -- --with-cflags=\"-O2 -pipe -march=native -w\"
```

Alternatively, if you wish to use bundler

```
export CONFIGURE_ARGS="--with-cflags='-O2 -pipe -march=native -w'"
bundle install --path vendor
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. same result as any of the above in the original post.